# imageButton bordres of an image

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have an app with Buttons that are rounded in form on an elliptic way, so when I put them over a imageButton, the image button appears like this

[image]

But I want the ImageButton to show only the image and not the borders of a Button

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to make ur own custom button,

Try this. create a file btn_default.xml in drawable and paste this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default" />
</selector>
```

create the rounded images u want the button to have in different state, i.e when the button is pressed, default, etc, and place them in the drawable folder the names mention in the above code or change the name of the drawable above.

Once this is done set btn_default.xml as the background of ur normal button.

Answer (score 3):

The `ImageButton` is to be used for exactly this - when you want an image inside a regular button. If you do not want the button background, just use an `ImageView`, or a regular `Button` where you change the background to your own button graphic (although the first option is probably the best in this case, as it seems like your button text is part of the image).

If you for some reason really *have* to use an `ImageButton`, set the `background` attribute to a transparent color or @null to get rid of the borders.

Answer (score 2):

Use an ImageView instead of an ImageButton. Basically, they are the same except that ImageButton puts the image inside of an existing button.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is defined in xml, you can set the android:background attribute to "@null." If it's created in code, use the button's setBackgroundDrawable() method, with null as your parameter.